# Docker automated build shows empty Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

I have created a Dockerfile [here](https://github.com/aquavitae/dockerfiles/blob/master/gunicorn-py3/Dockerfile) and set up automated build for it on the docker hub, but nothing seems to happen.  The build just shows "pending" and the [Dockerfile](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/aquavitae/gunicorn-py3/dockerfile/) on docker hub is empty.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The Dockerfile on the hub gets updated *after* the build runs.  Also, the pending for the build means it just hasn't run yet.  Sometimes it takes a while.  Do you have your github account Linked in the Settings section of the Docker repository? You can reach the status page to see if anything is broken here: https://status.docker.com/.

By the way, I have several projects on Docker hub, I went to one of them just now and clicked 'Build' (this isn't necessary if your github is linked, the auto build does that), and it is stuck in Pending.  Sometimes it takes a LONG time.

There has been at least one outage at Docker registry in the last 3 months while I was actively using it.  This might not be an outage, but, it could be :-(  It could also be a big load on Docker hub.

Comment: How long is a long time?  It takes a couple of min locally (including apt downloads over my rather slow connection), but the start time on docker hub is almost an hour ago.

Comment: I don't know how long.  Pending means it is scheduled, but, it hasn't started yet.  That is, nothing is happening.  You know, there are other repos you can use: https://quay.io/

Comment: I didn't know - thanks!  If an hour is not unreasonable then that's fine, I can wait.  I just worried that I had made a mistake that was causing this.  Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: it is usually pretty fast, something must be wrong up there?  Mine is still pending as well, it has been 30 minutes.  Usually it starts almost instantly.

Answer (score 1):

You just started the job in the time, when the build-stack was stuck. Its related to this:
https://forums.docker.com/t/build-stuck-in-pending-on-docker-hub/1360
Now, the issue is resolved and automated build should be fine.